# How to register a non-blocking Global Hotkey in Windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio, windows-10

I have searched quite thoroughly for this specific question on both Google, and SO. I can not find a question/answer that fits my needs exactly.

So what I need to do specifically is create a non-blocking global hot-key binding in Windows. (Windows 10 specifically, but windows, in general, is fine.)

By non-blocking I mean a global hotkey which does not prevent, stop, or otherwise impede any other application from using the hotkey, locally, or globally.

For example, if I registered the key: F1

I would be able to switch to another application, and when I press F1 the application specific local binding of F1 would fire, as well as my applications global binding of F1.

Firstly, is this possible? Secondly, am I thinking about this in the correct way? Is there another way to achieve this behavior without a global hotkey?

if it's possible where do I start? I have read through .Net's hotkey binding code and I have not seen any mentions of binding hotkeys which do not block other applications from using the same hotkey.

If not, what could be another way to go about implementing this behavior?

Thank you.

Comment: Use SetWindowsHookEx() instead of RegisterHotKey().

Comment: Hello Hands Passant; I found this when researching your solution.

"Global hooks are not supported in the .NET Framework"

From:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/318804/how-to-set-a-windows-hook-in-visual-c--net

Comment: I'm a bit disappointed that something so commonplace is not supported in C#.

To install a global hook, a hook must have a native DLL export to inject itself in another process that requires a valid, consistent function to call into. This behavior requires a DLL export. The .NET Framework does not support DLL exports. Managed code has no concept of a consistent value for a function pointer because these function pointers are proxies that are built dynamically.

Anyone have another solution?